# Saving model h5 in keras proceduces low performances in precision

Tags: model, keras, conv-neural-network, h5py

I have developed/implemented a CNET by using Keras where after a

```
 model.fit()
```

I have saveed correctly the model with:

```
 model.save('my_model_CNET32.h5')
```

If at the end of training process **without saving the model** I test the performances by using the *test dataset* I obtain 99% of precision, while by saving the model and then reloading it by using:

```
 model = load_model('my_model_CNET32.h5')
```

in a new script dedicated only to the test what the CNET has learned, I obtain 70%.

**Note that**, obviously, the *test dataset* are perfectly the same, I can deduce that the performances in classification are lower due to failing in *saving* the model.

Do you know what could be the cause of this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you using the .evaluate() function keras provides? If yes, could you build your own function using .predict() and a manual calculation of the error? I remember something weird about evaluate if your number of samples isn't a multiple of your batch size.

Comment: There seem to be an (endless...) ongoing discussion on this issue in the Keras forum: [model.save and load giving different result](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/4875)

Answer (score 0):

This is a similar problem I had with my CNET.
The problem might be one of those:

- Keras saves the model in the *.h5* format in the wrong way. Although the .h5 format is still supported in Keras, by looking at the developer guides it seems it's better to save the model in the new [SavedModel](https://keras.io/guides/serialization_and_saving/#savedmodel-format) format because it saves everything, from the architecture to the optimizer state of the model.
- It isn't specified the right accuracy metric in the **compile** method of the model. This is something I found from those two issues:

  1. [Keras giving low accuracy after loading model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64541824/keras-giving-low-accuracy-after-loading-model)
  2. [Accuracy is lost after save/load](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/42459)