# Keras giving low accuracy after loading model

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am seeing a very strange situation. After training a convolutional network I get about 95% accuracy on the validation data. I save the model. Later I restore the model and run validation on the same validation data set. This time I barely get 10% accuracy. I have read the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize) but nothing seems to help. Is there something I am doing wrong?

```py
def build_model_mnist(image_width, image_height, image_depth):
  model = keras.Sequential()
  model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(5, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(image_width, image_height, image_depth)))
  model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
  model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(10, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
  model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
  model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(10, (3, 3), activation='relu'))

  model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
  model.add(keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
  model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

  model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                metrics=['accuracy'])
  
  return model

def train_mnist():
  model = build_model_mnist(image_width=train_images.shape[1], 
                    image_height=train_images.shape[2], 
                    image_depth=train_images.shape[3])
  # Start training              
  h = model.fit(train_images, train_labels, batch_size=500, epochs=5)

  model.save("minist")

  # Evaluate the model
  test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_images, test_labels)

  print("Accuracy:", test_acc)

train_mnist()
```

The above will show 95% accuracy. But the code below shows 10% accuracy.

```py
def evaluate_mnist():
  # Load the model
  model = keras.models.load_model("minist")

  # Evaluate the model
  test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_images, test_labels)

  print("Accuracy:", test_acc)

evaluate_mnist()
```

If I save and restore just the weights then things work fine. In the code below we are saving the weights only. Later we recreate the model architecture using code and restore the weights. This approach produces the correct accuracy.

```py
def train_mnist():
  #Create the network model
  model = build_model_mnist(image_width=train_images.shape[1], 
                    image_height=train_images.shape[2], 
                    image_depth=train_images.shape[3])
  # Start training              
  h = model.fit(train_images, train_labels, batch_size=500, epochs=5)

  # Evaluate the model
  test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_images, test_labels)

  print("Accuracy:", test_acc)

  model.save_weights("minist-weights")

train_mnist()

def evaluate_mnist():
  # Re-create the model architecture
  model = build_model_mnist(image_width=train_images.shape[1], 
                    image_height=train_images.shape[2], 
                    image_depth=train_images.shape[3])

  model.load_weights("minist-weights")
  
  # Evaluate the model
  test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_images, test_labels)

  print("Accuracy:", test_acc)

evaluate_mnist()
```

Comment: Could you try saving the architecture to a file as json then save the weights using ```model.save_weights('path')```. Then load it using ```model = tf.keras.models.model_from_json('path')``` and ```model.load_weights('path')```. Finally try compiling it.

Comment: If I save just the weights and restore the weights then things work fine. I get the same accuracy after loading. There is something wrong going on with saving and loading the architecture. I am adding this observation to my question.

Comment: Seems to be an ongoing [issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/4875) with Keras.

Comment: What happens if you load the saved model, then after it is loaded, do model.load_weights using the saved weights? Might give a hint about what is going wrong. If this gives the correct results then it indicates model.save is not saving the proper weights.

Comment: @GerryP As I have noted if I just save and load the weights (and not the architecture) things work fine. I have gone through the GitHub issue pointed out by yudhiesh and this seems to be affecting a lot of people including this question. I am waiting to upgrade to a newer TF and Keras and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: You said your problem is that the saved MODEL when reloaded and run gives the wrong result so I thought you were trying to resolve that problem. I know saving and reloading the weights works if you recreate the model rather than reload it from a saved model but it doesn't resolve how to save and use a saved model. So I thought loading the saved model, then setting its weights with saved weights might solve that problem. Another solution is to try to save the model as a .h5 file. That works for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem in tf 2.3.0.

This [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/42459) explains the problem with the generic term "accuracy" metric when using sparse_categorical_crossentropy. On model reloading it associates the wrong accuracy metric.
The solution is to explicitly tell keras to use the correct metric instead of letting it infer what is the correct one (bug in it) i.e. compile with metrics='sparse_categorical_accuracy'.

I was using metrics='accuracy' initially as metric in training phase and discovered that only by recompiling the model after reloading it gave back the expected performance.

Answer (score 0):

For me though, I was also stuck because of this error, but after reading my code for 2 to 3 times, I found that the  program was taking the model which was declared before training `(model = keras.Sequential())`, and it was confusing that with the model after saving `(model = keras.models.load_model("minist"))`. To solve that, after saving the model with the weights, I removed the following lines :

```
model = keras.Sequential(), and all the model.add() lines
model.fit(train_images, train_labels, batch_size=500, epochs=5)
```

After commenting out these lines my network worked like a charm.
It helped me, hope it helps you.