# Tensorflow 2.3 problems with saving and loading model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

So after I saved my model with `model.save('path')` yesterday, I only found out today that there is some problem with tf 2.3 and keras saving the model. The problem is already described here: [Keras giving low accuracy after loading model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64541824/keras-giving-low-accuracy-after-loading-model/65237653) .
But the accepted solution doesn't help me. When I load the model using `model = tf.keras.models.load_model('path')` it returns a lower test accuracy than before saving it. Using

```
model.compile(optimizer = SGD(lr = 1e-3, momentum = 0.9, decay = 1e-6), #RMSProp
             loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
             metrics = ['sparse_categorical_accuracy'])
```

did not help because before saving the model I used 'accuracy' and not 'sparse_categorical_accuracy' and I'm now getting the following error when trying to train or test the model:

```
InvalidArgumentError:  Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 2
     [[node Squeeze (defined at <ipython-input-34-11b07af8f987>:4) ]] [Op:__inference_test_function_363481]

Function call stack:
test_function
```

So now my question: is there any way to load my saved model and get the saved state or do I need to restart training from zero again?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `metrics = ["accuracy"]` during training, tensorflow automatically takes the correct accuracy for your loss function.
The accuracy metric for `"sparse_categorical_crossentropy"` is `"sparse_categorical_accuracy"`. And in your case the accuracy metric for `"binary_crossentropy"` is `"binary_accuracy"`.

See all the metrics here : https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/

Always compile the model with the accuacy needed for your data.

```
model.compile(optimizer = SGD(lr = 1e-3, momentum = 0.9, decay = 1e-6),
             loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
             metrics = ['binary_accuracy'])
```

Comment: That makes sense thank you, sadly it doesn't solve my problem and I'm still not getting the correct accuracy :(

Answer (score 0):

As trivial as that may sound, did you check your the input data after loading the model? Is it preprocessed in exactly the same way as it was during training?

Most common: normalization and prefetching

Testing the loaded model with non normalized data (after beeing trained with normalization) will result in a bad performance, as you described.

The following works in my experience even with CustomMaskWarning.

```
# Saving
model.save(path)
# Loading
model = tf.keras.models.load_model(path)

# for only saving weights
model.save_weights(path)
# loading weights
model = create_model()  # create exactly the same model as trained
model.load_weights(path)
```

(The ".h5" format causes issues if you have CustomMaskWarning and didnt resolve them by overriding get_config and setting a config.)